# Http Trigger Azure function should not accessible outside from App Service

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions

I am using http trigger azure function in my App Service. I want this http trigger azure function should not accessible publicly and accessible only from the App Service.

Currently I have created host key for http trigger function and I am using this for authenticate request.

Which authentication method should I use for this? Any thoughts.

Azure Function:

```
public static class RemoveSubscriptionsForPayers
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(RemoveSubscriptionsForPayers))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] ICommandValidator commandValidator,
            [Inject] ICommandHandler<ResultDto,RemoveSubscriptionsForPayersCommand> commandHandler)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);

            try
            {
                IActionResult actionResult = null;

                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

                logger.Info($"RemoveSubscriptionsForPayersCommand received on {nameof(RemoveSubscriptionsForPayers)}");

                var command = requestBody.AsPoco<RemoveSubscriptionsForPayersCommand>();

                if (commandValidator.Validate<RemoveSubscriptionsForPayersCommand>(req, command, new RemoveSubscriptionsForPayersCommandValidator(), logger, ref actionResult))
                {
                    var response =await commandHandler.HandleAsync(command, logger);
                    actionResult = new OkObjectResult(response);
                }

                return actionResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Exception while processing {nameof(RemoveSubscriptionsForPayers)}", ex,
                  nameof(RemoveSubscriptionsForPayers));

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't Azure AD solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks! for your reply. I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure AD to authenticate your functions, which is more secure.

[image]

[image]

After opening Azure AD authentication, you need to obtain an access token.

Please open `Azure active directory` in the Azure portal and find `App registrations`, you need to search for the function you registered in Azure AD in the search box.

[image]

you need to find the parameter values of the url and body to obtain the token here.

[URL to get access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8AJj.png)

Body:

- [client_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOdm8.png)
- [scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMczF.png)
- [username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9MNd.png)
- grant_type: The value of `grant_type` is fixed, both are `password`.
- [client_secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAGdT.png)

You can get Token like this:

[image]

Now you can use the access token of Azure AD to access your functions.

The request header name is `Authorization`, and the header value is `Bearer <access-token>`:

[image]